# How can I get a count of Sublist inside list in scala?

Tags: scala, collections

I have a `List(List(15,21),List(10,18))`

1. I want to get first count of total subList `//here is 2`
2. I want to get only last subList `// List(10,18)`

I am new in scala.
Does anyone help which approach is good here.

Comment: What have you tried? Why it didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
val listOfList = List(List(15,21),List(10,18))
val size = listOfList.length // 2
val lastList = listOfList.last // List(10,18)
```

Comment: But in listOflist.length I got only 1 size...as we have only 1 element in the list.

Comment: are you sure? it's not possible it should give you 2 for length and last list for last

Comment: I have generated Spark RDD as below: val finalList = nums.map { num => num.toList }
    finalList.foreach(println); // List(15, 21) List(10, 18) and here I want to do sum of like (15+10, 21+18) in spark.